# Why is the angle of a triangular prism equal to the result of the following 2 calculations? (Experiment with optical goniometer)

Tags: optics, measurements

I know there are two ways of measuring the angle of a prism with a goniometer:

> let the collimator shine (monochromatic) light on 2 sides of the prism and measure the angle between the 2 reflected lightbeams.

or

> Let the lightbeam hit one side of the prism, note down the position of the the table of the goniometer where the prism is on (=$\beta_1$) and check the location of the reflected lightbeam, turn the table around counter-clockwise until the reflected lightbeam is in the same place and note down that position (=$\beta_2$).

Now, my problem is that, while I understand completely how to perform these actions, I don't understand why:
In the first case the measured angle is the angle of the prism times two.
In the second case when subtracting $|\beta_1-\beta_2$| from $180°$ you get the angle of the prism.

Comment: You seem to have all of the necessary information in your post.  Could you clarify what aspect of the problem you don't understand?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that I just don't understand why the angle of the prism is those 2 values in the two cases, if that makes sense. i.e. How do you know that the angle you measured in the first method is twice the angle of the prism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you only need one rule:  "The angle of reflection equals the angle of incidence."  Draw a triangle on a piece of paper. ( For this situation, the third dimension of the prism is irrelevant). Draw two parallel lines originating from roughly the direction the apex of the prism is pointing.  It's not necessary to be exactly in that direction, as you'll see.  Those lines hit the two sides of the prism and reflect, relative to the normal to the surface, according to the rule I quoted.
Since you know (I hope! ) about complementary angles and the various theorems from trigonometry about the interior and exterior angles of a triangle, you'll soon see why the formula works.

The second formulation is similar, although you have added the possibility of an error term due to inexact reading of the goniometer.